# How to mock promisified Mysql data using sinon for Unit Testing

Tags: mysql, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

Is it possible to mock promisified queries in NodeJS using sinon for `require('promise-mysql')`  npm package. As Sinon allows us to mock and / or stub out methods on objects. Say I want to override the createConnection() method so that it returns a valid object regardless of whether the database settings were right or not, I'd stub out that method. I am able to mock that using `require('mysql')` npm package which is having callbacks.

But, as `require('promise-mysql')` package returns promise, I am not sure about how to mock test data for same.

For `require('mysql')` package this is working perfectly

```
var successConnectionObject = {
        connect: function(cb) {
            cb();
        },
        query: function(sqlQury, cb) {
            if (sqlQury === 'SELECT * FROM USERS') {
                cb(null, constants.USERQueryResp);
            } else {
                cb(null, '');
            }
        },
        end: function() {} 
}

var testMysqlDriver = require('mysql');
var stub = sinon.stub(testMysqlDriver, 'createConnection');
stub.returns(successConnectionObject);

 publish.handler(some_JSON_Request, some_Context_Values, function(err, data) {
    expect(data.message).toBe(USER_Query_Response);
    done();
});
```

how can we achieve same this using `require('promise-mysql');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject` as return values

```
var successConnectionObject = {
        connect: function() {
            return Promise.resolve()
        },
        query: function(sqlQury) {
            if (sqlQury === 'SELECT * FROM USERS') {
                return Promise.resolve(constants.USERQueryResp);
            } else {
                return Promise.resolve(';')
            }
        },
        end: {function() {} 
}
```

If your `nodejs` version don't have `Promise`, you can use `bluebird`, or any other Promise library

```
var Promise=require('bluebird')
```